# Why does this code fail to print all the values in a queue?

Tags: c++

Can you explain why the code does not print the all the values in a Queue, q.

```
for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << q.dequeue() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Please learn how to write [mcve]

Comment: How is this queue class defined? There is no standard library container or adapter which has a member function named `dequeue`.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `q.dequeue()` then obviously `q.size()` will decrease, and you will only ever output around half of your queue elements. So you probably want to cache the initial size before you start iterating, e.g.

```
const size_t n = q.size();
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    std::cout << q.dequeue() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar in logic to Paul R's answer above. The items in the queue are all being dequeued, so loop until the queue is empty.

```
while (q.size()) 
{
    std::cout << q.dequeue() << std::endl;
}
```